# How to display a formatted weekdays from a given Week number

Tags: php, strtotime

I'm getting the weekdays from a given week number and year using the php below:

```
$week_number = 42; 
$year = 2014; 
for($day = 1; $day<=7; $day++)
   {
     echo date('m/d/Y',strtotime($year."W".          $week_number.$day));
  }
```

The Output look likes this:

```
   10/13/2014
   10/14/2014
   10/15/2014
   10/16/2014
   10/17/2014
   10/18/2014
   10/19/2014
```

How can I make it look just like this:

```
 Oct 13 - Oct 19.
```

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation for `date`?

Comment: Don't do this in a loop, since you want only start and end of the week.

Comment: whoever is downvoting should please give a reason.

Comment: @Tomasz What close reasons ? Does it look like I've put no effort in this. I dont understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php

$week_number = 42; 
$year = 2014; 
echo date('M d',strtotime($year."W".$week_number . 1)) . " - " . date('M d',strtotime($year."W".$week_number . 7)).".";
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$week_number = 42; 
$year = 2014; 

$week_number = ($week_number < 10) ? '0'.$week_number : $week_number;
echo date('M d',strtotime($year.'W'.$week_number.'1')).' - '.date('M d',strtotime($year.'W'.$week_number.'7')).'.';

// remember that $week_number must be prefixed with 0 if week number is lower than 10
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `strftime`

here is the link http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php

Answer (score 1):

Then use

```
date("F j, D");for your date function
```